# меню 3 уровня css html

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, modx

подскажите как сделать, чтобы подменю второго уровня без подменю отображались как на фото?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
}
.nav .item_top>.sub{
    margin-top: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 32;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.08);
    padding: 20px;
}
.nav .item_top>.sub>.item_sub{
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
<div class="item_top">
  <a href="/" class="first"> Главная </a>
</div>
  <div class="item_top">
    <a href="katalog/" class="catalog-link"> Каталог </a>
    <div class="sub">
      <div class="item_sub">
        <a href="verxnyaya-odezhda/"> Верхняя одежда</a>
       <div class="sub">
       <div class="item_sub">
        <a href="palto/"> Пальто</a>
       </div>
       <div class="item_sub">
        <a href="kardiganyi/"> Кардиганы</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="item_sub">
      <a href="teplaya-odezhda/"> Теплая одежда</a>
     </div>
    <div class="item_sub">
      <a href="legkaya-odezhda/"> Легкая одежда</a>
     <div class="sub">
      <div class="item_sub">
        <a href="futbolki/"> Футболки</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="item_sub">
      <a href="niz/"> Низ</a>
     <div class="sub">
      <div class="item_sub">
        <a href="bryuki/"> Брюки</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="item_sub"><a href="platya/"> Платья</a></div>
    <div class="item_sub"><a href="kostyumyi/"> Костюмы</a></div>   <div class="item_sub"><a href="aksessuaryi/"> Аксессуары</a></div>
    <div class="item_sub"><a href="kombinezonyi/"> Комбинезоны</a></div>
    <div class="item_sub"><a href="zhiletki/"> Жилетки</a></div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно что вам нужно. Для начала.

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav .item_top>.sub {
  margin-top: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 32;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav .item_top>.sub>.item_sub {
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.nav .item_top {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav .item_top a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.item_top .sub .item_sub .sub {
  margin: 10px;
}

.nav .item_top .sub a {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="item_top">
    <a href="/" class="first"> Главная </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item_top">
    <a href="katalog/" class="catalog-link"> Каталог </a>
    <div class="sub">
      <div class="item_sub">
        <a href="verxnyaya-odezhda/"> Верхняя одежда</a>
        <div class="sub">
          <div class="item_sub">
            <a href="palto/"> Пальто</a>
          </div>
          <div class="item_sub">
            <a href="kardiganyi/"> Кардиганы</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item_sub">
        <a href="teplaya-odezhda/"> Теплая одежда</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item_sub">
        <a href="legkaya-odezhda/"> Легкая одежда</a>
        <div class="sub">
          <div class="item_sub">
            <a href="futbolki/"> Футболки</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item_sub">
        <a href="niz/"> Низ</a>
        <div class="sub">
          <div class="item_sub">
            <a href="bryuki/"> Брюки</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item_sub"><a href="platya/"> Платья</a></div>
      <div class="item_sub"><a href="kostyumyi/"> Костюмы</a></div>
      <div class="item_sub"><a href="aksessuaryi/"> Аксессуары</a></div>
      <div class="item_sub"><a href="kombinezonyi/"> Комбинезоны</a></div>
      <div class="item_sub"><a href="zhiletki/"> Жилетки</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Без подкатегорий, скрываем с помощью css:

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav .item_top>.sub {
    margin-top: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    display: block;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    /* justify-content: space-between; */
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 32;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
    padding: 20px;
}

.nav .item_top>.sub>.item_sub {
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav .item_top {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav .item_top a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.item_top .sub .item_sub .sub {
  margin: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.nav .item_top .sub a {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="item_top">
    <a href="/" class="first"> Главная </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item_top">
    <a href="katalog/" class="catalog-link"> Каталог </a>
    <div class="sub">
      <div class="item_sub">
        <a href="verxnyaya-odezhda/"> Верхняя одежда</a>
        <div class="sub">
          <div class="item_sub">
            <a href="palto/"> Пальто</a>
          </div>
          <div class="item_sub">
            <a href="kardiganyi/"> Кардиганы</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item_sub">
        <a href="teplaya-odezhda/"> Теплая одежда</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item_sub">
        <a href="legkaya-odezhda/"> Легкая одежда</a>
        <div class="sub">
          <div class="item_sub">
            <a href="futbolki/"> Футболки</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item_sub">
        <a href="niz/"> Низ</a>
        <div class="sub">
          <div class="item_sub">
            <a href="bryuki/"> Брюки</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item_sub"><a href="platya/"> Платья</a></div>
      <div class="item_sub"><a href="kostyumyi/"> Костюмы</a></div>
      <div class="item_sub"><a href="aksessuaryi/"> Аксессуары</a></div>
      <div class="item_sub"><a href="kombinezonyi/"> Комбинезоны</a></div>
      <div class="item_sub"><a href="zhiletki/"> Жилетки</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav .item_top>.sub {
  margin-top: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 32;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav .item_top>.sub>.item_sub {
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav .item_top {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav .item_top a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.item_top .sub .item_sub .sub {
  margin: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.nav .item_top .sub a {
  color: #000000;
}

.stolbik {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="item_top">
    <a href="/" class="first"> Главная </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item_top">
    <a href="katalog/" class="catalog-link"> Каталог </a>
    <div class="sub">
      <div class="stolbik">
        <div class="item_sub">
          <a href="verxnyaya-odezhda/"> Верхняя одежда</a>
          <div class="sub">
            <div class="item_sub">
              <a href="palto/"> Пальто</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item_sub">
              <a href="kardiganyi/"> Кардиганы</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item_sub">
          <a href="teplaya-odezhda/"> Теплая одежда</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item_sub">
          <a href="legkaya-odezhda/"> Легкая одежда</a>
          <div class="sub">
            <div class="item_sub">
              <a href="futbolki/"> Футболки</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item_sub">
          <a href="niz/"> Низ</a>
          <div class="sub">
            <div class="item_sub">
              <a href="bryuki/"> Брюки</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item_sub"><a href="platya/"> Платья</a></div>
        <div class="item_sub"><a href="kostyumyi/"> Костюмы</a></div>
        <div class="item_sub"><a href="aksessuaryi/"> Аксессуары</a></div>
        <div class="item_sub"><a href="kombinezonyi/"> Комбинезоны</a></div>
        <div class="item_sub"><a href="zhiletki/"> Жилетки</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Давайте без минусов. Я не собираюсь весь код переписывать. Остальное самостоятельно.

Comment: нет просто мне нужно чтобы без подкатегорий в столбец выводились справа как  платья, комбинизоны

Comment: @extrememod я добавил второй вариант в ответ. Если я правильно тебя понял, то, скрываем подкатегории. Но, лучше это делать на языке программирования. В данном случае, с помощью css.